# How can I optimize this code to cope with a larger dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing

I have a set of images with the same size. And I want to insert them into a dataframe, with the rows being the names of the images and the columns being the pixels. They are all in the same directory.

- I can already do this for a folder with a few images (as shown in the "Example for 7 images" link below), but when I try it for a dataset with 9912 images, the compile shows "killed". How can I optimize this code to get all the images?

```
from matplotlib import image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob


columns = ["file"]
for i in range (150528):
    columns.append("pixel" + str(i))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
i = 0
for file in glob.glob('/home/nuno/resizepics/*.jpg'): 
    imgarr = image.imread(file)
    imgarr = imgarr.flatten()

    df.loc[i,"file"] = file
    for j in range(len(imgarr)):
        df.iloc[i,j+1] = imgarr[j]

    i += 1

#print(df)


df.to_csv('pixels.csv')
```

[Example for 7 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTMv6.png)

Comment: What do you want to "optimize" ? You are trying to stuff lots of data in some container that seems can't take more. And what do you mean by "the compile shows "killed"" ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust and what can I do to achieve this with a larger amount of data? By "killed" I mean that it takes a long time to compile and then appears in the terminal "Morto", which in English means "dead/killed"

Comment: Python is an interpreted language. It does not "compile".

Comment: Uh ? Are you really trying to create a monstrous Excel sheet with 1492033536 cells ? What is the purpose of "flattening" the pixels, this is crazy !

Comment: 150528 yeah, to train and try to predict a score

Comment: You are probably not using the right tool.

Comment: @YvesDaoust probably, but can you help change that code that works for a few images, work for thousands?

Comment: 1) I guess that this is a nonsense. 2) I guess that this is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

If "killed" means it raises an error you can try using `exeptions (try, except, else)` and make it try again from the spot it stopped. You can also try to delay it a bit with `time` module because it works with large data.